# How much domain class inheritance is too much in Grails?

Tags: grails, inheritance, grails-orm

From reading the [docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#inheritanceInGORM) in Grails I found the following statement:

> However, excessive use of inheritance and table-per-subclass can
>   result in poor query performance due to the use of outer join queries.
>   In general our advice is if you're going to use inheritance, don't
>   abuse it and don't make your inheritance hierarchy too deep.

My question is: how deep is too deep?

Will 5 extensions in an inheritance chain make Grails cry?, 10?, 20?... what is the criteria to determine this?, or do we know if there is a clear way to extrapolate such performance degradation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How deep is too deep?* is a rather subjective question. But, it's possible to make an educated guess when you consider what happens at the database level with table-per-subclass inheritance. Lets assume you have these domain classes:

```
class Employee {    
    String firstName
    String lastName

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }

}

class Supervisor extends Employee {
    String office

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

You'd end up with two tables: `EMPLOYEE` and `SUPERVISOR`. The `EMPLOYEE` table would contain the columns `id`, `first_name`, and `last_name`. But notice that the `SUPERVISOR` table would only contain the columns `id` and `office`.

This means that to retrieve a `Supervisor` GORM has to join both tables in order to populate the inherited properties.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE.ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, OFFICE
FROM   SUPERVISOR INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE 
       ON SUPERVISOR.ID = EMPLOYEE.ID
```

It's these joins which have the potential to result in reduced performance. As you can imagine, 10 or 20 levels of inheritance would be disastrous. Yet a few, especially if the tables are small, would likely be OK.

Besides, a deep inheritance hierarchy is a sign that something is probably wrong with the domain model architecture (ie. consider using Traits).

You can read more about both forms of inheritance in my article [here](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-inheritance/).